# Условия OEM лицензии Windows 7/8 - кто и на какие компьютеры может устанавливать?

Tags: windows, лицензирование

Добрый день, [предварительно поинтересовавшись](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/717/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-windows), уместно ли на этом форуме задавать подобные вопросы, решил все таки задать.

Вопрос мой возник после прочтения [Лицензия на Windows 7/8](https://toster.ru/q/46130) в поисках ответа на вопрос, какой самый дешевый способ лицензирования Windows (для работы).

**Вопрос: могу ли я как физическое лицо купить OEM Windows 8.1 Pro и установить на уже имеющийся комптьютер?**

Звонил в MS несколько раз и разные операторы говорили разную информацию: *одна говорит* "так тоже можно, но правильнее будет установка oem на новый комп.", *другая говорит* "ваша ОС конечно будет работать как лицензионная, но по лиц. соглашению, oem допустимо устанавливать только на новый комп.".
В то же время предлагают купить лицензию на 8.1 Pro по акции для студентов дешевле на 10 000 руб, говорят, даже если вы не являетесь студентом, вы можете достать любой студ. билет - но ведь это тоже "обходной" способ получается.

**Кто и на какие компьютеры можно устанавливать OEM Windows 7/8.1?**
В сети, кстати, можно найти интересные объявления, например [Windows 8.1, 8, 7 pro, server 2012 visio 2013](https://www.avito.ru/sankt-peterburg/igry_pristavki_i_programmy/windows_8.1_8_7_pro_server_2012_visio_2013_590234253).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что к программированию вопрос отношение имеет очень опосредованное.

Comment: А, по-моему, хороший вопрос, потому что вопрос лицензионности близок к теме программирования.

Comment: А еще я на стуле сижу когда программирую - про стулья тоже можно спрашивать?

Comment: Ну так спрашивают же - https://toster.ru/q/6042 (первое, что попалось, хотя подобных тем полно)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов тут еще и системное администрирование в тренде. А в администрировании лиценизирование - еще тот онтопик. особенно если это адиминистрирование под винду.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Считаю, вопросы лицензирования Windows являются неотъемлемой частью администрирования.

Answer (score 0):

OEM Windows 8 просто купить и поставить можно. А вот Windows 7 и для Windows 8.1 - нельзя. Условия лицензирования поменяли дважды - между 7 и 8, и между 8 и 8.1.

[Официальная таблица с условиями](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/windows-licensing-for-personal-use.aspx#fbid=N0W-_nOCiXV). Обратите внимание на оговорку для 8-ки:

> OEM System builder product may be purchased

Хотя для 7 и для 8.1:

> Full packaged retail product is needed.

[Длинная статья про это на howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/197232/microsoft-is-misleading-consumers-with-windows-8.1-system-builder-licensing/).

Comment: получается, я могу купить oem 8 pro, установить на свой имеющийся (не новый) комп., а потом бесплатно обновиться до 8.1 или даже 10? Не знаете, не будет ли нарушением лицензии, если покупать ключи у перепродавцов (цена привлекает)?